# Creating a new directory without mkdir()

Tags: c, mkdir, directory

In C I'm using 'open()' to create and open files:

```
fd = open(fileName, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
```

if 'fileName' includes a directory the file is created only if the directory exists and the application has permission to write to this directory.

If the directory does not exists 'open()' returns an error and I would like to create the directory.

With makedir (see below) I am able to create the directory.

```
int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

I was wondering, are there other ways to create a directory? I believe we can also use ioctl()? Are there more alternatives?

I'm asking this because in our code we are *not allowed* to use mkdir.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose system("mkdir foo") is not allowed?

Comment: Since a dir is represented as a file , I think you can create a file and play around with attributes to get there.

Comment: it seems odd that you are not allowed to use a well-known command like mkdir but instead want a hack to circumvent it. just my 2c

Comment: @RamBhat that should work, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @RamBhat No, it will not work. A file is different from a directory, even though you sometimes can open an existing directory as a file and read its entries. A directory requires completely different setup on a file system level.

Answer (score 5):

> I was wondering, are there other ways to create a directory? I believe we can also use ioctl()?

At least on Linux and HP-UX, `mkdir` is a system call on its own.

So, No, there is no other way to create a directory, at least not on Linux - other systems *might* implement directory creation differently. But on any reasonable system, I would expect directory creation to be a privileged operation, so you need to go through the kernel.

The only slightly different approach would be to execute the system call directly, by bypassing the `C` runtime library. In assembly nasm syntax on an i386 architecture, this would look something like

```
mkdir:
    mov     eax, 39         ; System-call "sys_mkdir"
    mov     ebx, dirName    ; directory name to create
    mov     ecx, 0x755      ; creation mode
    int     80H             ; call sys_mkdir
```

However, this is not something you would normally do since it is completely system dependant. Switching to a different CPU would require different register setup and/or different instructions - that is what the C runtime library encapsulates.

See also

- http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html
- http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call

Answer (score 0):

A kernel driver can create a folder using

```
struct file *fp = (struct file *) NULL;
fp = filp_open("/home/testdir", O_DIRECTORY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
```

I can imagine some situations when a "make_dir" driver which creates large number of folders will be faster than calling mkdir for every folder.